# Laravel - HTML5 Video not shown if two tabs are opened

Tags: html, video, laravel, laravel-4

I am developing an application in laravel which uploads files and stores them to a database and to the local storage on server. Then, I am retrieving the video information for filepath and filename and use that on an html5 video tag like this:

```
<video height="300px" controls>
      <source src="/assetlibr/public{{{ $upload->filepath }}}/{{{ $upload->filename }}}" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="/assetlibr/public{{{ $upload->filepath }}}/{{{ $upload->filename }}}" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The videos are showing but if I have two tabs opened with my application running the videos cannot be shown on the video tag, as a result to just get the video tag with a black area where the video was and the controls below like this:

[image]

This leads to not being able to playback the file. I am not sure why this happens, how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<video height="300px" controls>
    <source src="{{asset('assetlibr/public' . $upload->filepath . '/' . $upload->filename)}}" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="{{asset('assetlibr/public' . $upload->filepath . '/' . $upload->filename)}}" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Then, read this [article](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/04/12/html5-video-preload/).

Comment: Thanks, the article prompted me to get this problem fixed by adding a `preload="none"` attribute.